# How to setup Elixir on Sublime Text 3

Tags: elixir, sublimetext3

Hi I'm brand new to Elixir, haven't even ran a code yet. But I've downloaded it, downloaded the appropriate packages on sublime, restarted sublime and it doesn't work. And when I save a .ex file it doesn't get a logo, opposed to a .py file that gets the python logo. So I don't know if Sublime can't find the Elixir program, should it be added to my path? I don't know what to do here, and would love some help as I'm sitting in the dark, and can't find much support since Elixir isn't as widely used. And I'm really depending on this for a job opportunity. I appreciate any and all help!

Comment: At the bottom right you'll see some text that specifies what language sublime text is treating the current file as. It'll probably say "plain text", if you click that do you see Elixir?

Comment: @Downgoat it actually says Elixir! So do Elixir files just not get a icon with the logo? And if so why doesn't the touch function work? I guess these are questions for other threads. Sorry about that, I assumed because of these two things that it meant sublime wasn't loading it.

Comment: oh! ok in that case for the elixir icon you probably are going to need an icon package which has elixir icons. This is the one I use which works great: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/A%20File%20Icon

Comment: @Downgoat Thanks! I appreciate you! Is there a way we can possibly DM? If not I understand.

Comment: Stack exchange does not have DMs but if you continue needing help with this question you can ping me as you are doing, or you can open a new question

Comment: @Downgoat FWIW, stack exchange does indeed have kinda DM: https://chat.stackexchange.com/

Comment: While totally not an answer to your question, I can only say that the visual studio code integration of Elixir is exceptional. I highly recommend switching.

Answer (score 3):

I've installed following plugins in Sublime: `Elixir`, `Elixir Sublime` and `ElixirSyntax`.
File should be saved as `.exs` in order to be recognized by Sublime.
In case autocomple plugin does not work for you be sure that in Preferences/Settings the key "auto_complete" is set to `true`